# Highlight only text in table cell

Tags: html, css

I have an html table that is generated by java.  I'd like to simply highlight the text in a table cell without setting the background color to the entire cell.

I'll start by saying that I know I can do what I want by playing with the table cells.  However, this is late in the development stage and I don't really want spend a lot of time on this.

This is what they want:
[image]

But, if I format the cell using this:

```
<td style="width:20%;background-color:yellow;">Last:&nbsp;Thudpucker</style></td>
<td style="width:20%">First:&nbsp;Jimmy</td>
<td style="width:20%">Middle:&nbsp;T</td>
<td style="width:20%">DOB:&nbsp;12/12/1992</td>
```

I get this:

[image]

Is what they want possible with just html/css?

Comment: You're going to have to use some jQuery if you're not wanting to edit the HTML.

Comment: @ Alex: I don't mind editing the html, I just don't want to change the table structure and # of cells.  This is just a small part of a MUCH larger table and I've spent too much time on formatting as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `span` for this like....

```
<td style="width:20%;">Last:&nbsp;<span style="background-color:yellow;">Thudpucker</span></td>
<td style="width:20%">First:&nbsp;Jimmy</td>
<td style="width:20%">Middle:&nbsp;T</td>
<td style="width:20%">DOB:&nbsp;12/12/1992</td>
```

Comment: I tried that earlier.  It just ignores everything within the span tag, which effectively just removes the last name.

Comment: yeah, i tested it outside of my program and it works fine.  Yet, within the program, it ignores everything inside the span tag.  However, that does answer the question...just need to figure out what I screwed up inside that's causing it to ignore the span tag.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle for your code so i can understand your problem correctly..

Comment: Wish I could, but the whole thing is a lot more complicated than what I posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  tags around the word you'd like to highlight or HTML5's  tag if you don't care about IE8 and lower (or have a workaround for it) and style it with some css later, so:

```
<td style="width:20%">Last:&nbsp;<span>Thudpucker</span></style></td>
```

or:

```
<td style="width:20%">Last:&nbsp;<mark>Thudpucker</mark></style></td>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, IE8 is the office standard for the moment.  Good idea, tho, when we upgrade.